# How to check CPU, RAM and HDD information in GSA

Tags: gsa

I have 2 Google Search Appliance boxes and I have to check the Hardware information like CPU, Memory, Hard disk. Please let me know how to check this on the GSA.

Regards

Comment: Why? They're intended as a [black box appliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) ; *"a piece of equipment provided by a vendor, for the purpose of using that vendor's product. It is often the case that the vendor maintains and supports this equipment, and the company receiving the black box typically is hands-off."*

Comment: do you mean that we cannot check the hardware information on the box ? My question may look silly but I'm very new in using GSA and need help to know about GSA

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what model you have.

The information is kind of out there if you search with Google. I found this review of an older model GB-1001

http://stu.mp/2005/10/google-search-appliance-gb-1001-review.html

It says

- Quad 2.66GHz Intel Xeon
- 12GB of RAM
- Five 250GB Western Digital EIDE drives (Two 250GB RAID1 mirrors on a - 3ware ATA RAID card and one hot spare)

I wouldn't be surprised if you dig deeper you could verify and find more info on your model.

Comment: I can see the regulatory model is E02S. Is there any way that I can connect to the box and check the hardware configuration ?